# How to access parent element from 'change' event using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have the following code:

JavaScript:

```
        jQuery(".cbChild").on("change", function () {
            //go to parent checkbox to see if it's check.  If not, check it.
            var parentElement = jQuery(this).closest('cbParentContainer');

            //I've also tried
            //var parentElement = jQuery(this).parentsUntil('cbParentContainer');
            //And
            //var parentElement = jQuery(this).parentsUntil('row');

            if (jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked")) {
                parentElement.prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cbEventsContainer">
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-sm-4 cbParent"><input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$VirtualTourEventRegistration$rptEventList$ctl03$ctl00" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_ctl00" type="checkbox">
        <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_ctl00">Connect with Digital Services</label>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="cbChildContainer">        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">                            
        </div>
        <span class="checkbox col-sm-11 cbChild">
            <input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$VirtualTourEventRegistration$rptEventList$ctl03$rptEventRegistrationDetails$ctl00$ctl00" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl00_ctl00" type="checkbox">
            <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl00_ctl00">Event 1</label>
        </span>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">                            
        </div>
        <span class="checkbox col-sm-11 cbChild">
            <input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$VirtualTourEventRegistration$rptEventList$ctl03$rptEventRegistrationDetails$ctl01$ctl00" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl01_ctl00" type="checkbox">
            <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl01_ctl00">Event 2</label>
        </span>

    </div>        
</div>
```

When one of the child checkboxes (class='cbChild') gets checked, I want to force the parent (class='cbParent') checkbox to also be checked.  However, I'm unable to access the parent for some reason. The call to parentElement.prop("checked", true) fails because parentElement isn't the parent checkbox. To further clarify the issue, there are multiple cbEventsConainers with more parent/child checkboxes. I only included one for this post.

Comment: They are not a parent and childs, they all are cousins. Class names do not grant relationships in DOM.

Comment: cbParentContainer is the parent container  to the checkbox and  I can't access it.  I wasn't saying class names granted any relationship.  But the cbParentContainer encapsulates the top most checkbox in the list is our root checkbox. If any of the other two are checked then it has to be checked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not dealing with a child-parent relationship here but the following will check the "parent" checkbox when at least one of the children is checked and will uncheck it otherwise.

```js
$(function(){
 $("body").on("change",".cbChild input",function(){
  var cc=$(this).closest(".cbChildContainer"),p=cc.prev("div").find(".cbParent input");
  p.prop("checked",$(".cbChild input:checked",cc).length>0);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="cbEventsContainer">
<div class="row">
<span class="col-sm-4 cbParent"><input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$VirtualTourEventRegistration$rptEventList$ctl03$ctl00" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_ctl00" type="checkbox">
    <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_ctl00">Connect with Digital Services</label>
</span>
</div>
<div class="cbChildContainer">        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">                            
    </div>
    <span class="checkbox col-sm-11 cbChild">
        <input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$VirtualTourEventRegistration$rptEventList$ctl03$rptEventRegistrationDetails$ctl00$ctl00" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl00_ctl00" type="checkbox">
        <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl00_ctl00">Event 1</label>
    </span>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">                            
    </div>
    <span class="checkbox col-sm-11 cbChild">
        <input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$VirtualTourEventRegistration$rptEventList$ctl03$rptEventRegistrationDetails$ctl01$ctl00" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl01_ctl00" type="checkbox">
        <label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl01_VirtualTourEventRegistration_rptEventList_ctl03_rptEventRegistrationDetails_ctl01_ctl00">Event 2</label>
    </span>

</div>        
</div>
```

Comment: I modified your code to also do the reverse.  If the "Parent" checkbox is unchecked, it now unchecks all "Child" checkboxes. Very helpful - thanks again.